# Create Appointment in shared/delegate calendar

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing a VSTO outlook addin, that will create an appointment/meeting.  I use the following code to create the appointment/meeting:

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)

If the user clicks into a different calendar that they have delegate access to how can I create the appointment in the selected delegate calendar?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selected folder can be retrieved from Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Other user's Calendar folder can be retrieved using Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder.

Once  you have the MAPIFolder object, you can call MAPIFolder.Items.Add to create a new appointment.